# What are the practical reasons for not using underscores in Twitter usernames, if any?

Tags: twitter, username

Unfortunately my desired twitter username is taken. For hypothetical purposes let's say it's `AnnaGoesHome`. There are lot variations of prefixes and suffixes I can use such as `TheAnnaGoesHome`, `AnnaGoesHomeCom`, `IamAnnaGoesHome`.

`Anna_Goes_Home` is nice because it's still feels like the exact desired name with no additional words, but most recommend not using underscores. What are the practical reasons for not using underscores in a twitter username? (i.e. what are the true cons?)

Comment: Because it looks bad? Because at 140 characters @replies with underscores would seem to take up too much space? This seems like it's asking for opinions.

Comment: And, frankly, I see plenty of people with underscores in their Twitter handles.

Comment: @AlE. I'm not asking for stylistic reasons (i.e. it looks bad).  I'm wondering what are the non-stylistic reasons for not using underscores.  I don't see that as asking for opinions.

Comment: Underscores are inconveniently buried on iOS keyboards (number and symbols -> special symbols).

Answer (score 8):

Twitter fully  supports underscores in usernames; their [support article](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/twitter-username-rules) even recommends it to those unable to get their preferred handle.

> Adding underscores before or after your desired username will help you claim a unique handle on Twitter.

But therein lies a rub; having an underscore-containing name sends the message that you were late to the party or otherwise failed to get what you wanted. Who'd want to follow such a loser?

I can think of only one *objective* reason to prefer underscore-less names: underscores are harder to type on mobile keyboards than letters or numbers. It's not often that users enter  someone's Twitter handle manually, but it does happen.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to promote your Twitter handle off-line especially in spoken formats,  eg announcing at a conference  "follow Anna_goes_home on Twitter for live-tweet updates, then the underscore is a pain.  It's hard to vocalise, and a fair proportion of non-tech-heads won't even know what an "underscore" is.

But if your promotions are totally on-line using clickable links, then I don't see the underscore as a problem.